# Why do I get a contradiction using Markov's and Chebyshev's inequality on this coin flipping problem?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Suppose a coin gives heads $H$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. I flip it $100$ times and would like to estimate the upper bound on probability that I get more than or equal to $35$ heads.

If $X$ denotes number of heads in $100$ flips, then $E(X) = 25$ and $Var(X) = \frac{75}{4}$.

Applying Markov's inequality, I have that $P(X \geq 35) \leq \frac{25}{35} = \frac{5}{7}$. However applying Chebyshev's inequality, I have, since $\{X \geq 35\} \subset \{|X-25| \geq 10 \}$, the result:

$P(X \geq 35) \leq P(|X-25| \geq 10 ) \leq \frac{\frac{75}{4}}{100} = \frac{3}{16},$

which is smaller than $\frac{5}{7}$.

Isn't this contradictory? Markov gives a one sided bound, and this one sided bound is greater than the two-sided bound obtained by Chebyshev. Intuitively, one would expect that probability of getting 35 heads or more would be less than probability of getting either 35 heads or more, or 15 heads or less...

Comment: Not sure I am following.  $5<10$ and $5<7$.  Is that a contradiction?

Comment: To stress:  both of those bounds are absolutely awful.  That's the nature of those inequalities...they apply to all distributions (within reason) but they aren't very good.  It's easy to get the exact answer here, or to use the normal distribution to get a good approximation.  Worth doing for comparison purposes.

Comment: Contradiction is that the bound I get from Markov is larger than from Chebyshev. But Chebyshev gives a "two-sided bound", hence it should be larger than Markov, no? @lulu

Comment: No.  Chebyshev has better information.  It uses the variance of the distribution.  The only good thing about Markov is that it is universal (well, you need $E[X]$ to exist, but that's all). Aside from that, it is a terrible estimator.  Lots of times it just tells you that the probability you want is bounded by something greater than $1$.

Comment: Worth emphasizing:  Here $\sigma = \sqrt {100\times .25\times .75}=4.33$ so you are asking about a $2.3\sigma $ event.  That's not impossible, surely, but the probability is low.  Nowhere near $\frac 57$.

Comment: Does Chebyshev always give a bound less than $1$? @lulu

Comment: Certainly not.  The bound is $\frac {\sigma^2}{a^2}$ so just take $|a|<\sigma$.  But you shouldn't be using these estimates for such small values of $a$.

Comment: Don't want to sound like I am criticizing these estimates.  They are fantastically useful.  But they are really only useful when you have very little information about the distribution.  If, as in your problem, you know a lot about the distribution, you can do *a lot*  better.

Comment: In such a problem as given here, what other inequalities can be used for bounds? Forgetting we can use normal approximation, etc. @lulu

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Since we know the distribution exactly, we can just read off the answer.   [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vysochanskij%E2%80%93Petunin_inequality) is a refinement of Chebyshev that requires your distribution to be unimodal (as yours is).